# Console app doesn't work with mysql connector, in IDE it does work

Tags: java, console-application, mysql-connector

So, I have a program meant to be run from a terminal which should connect to a mysql server locally on the machine the program runs on. There is however a conflict where the connector is seen as a main program as well ( I think). it throws this error when run from terminal:

```java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at nu.educom.dbInsert.MySqlConn.getConn(MySqlConn.java:25)
    at nu.educom.dbInsert.ConsoleApp.start(ConsoleApp.java:56)
    at nu.educom.dbInsert.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

I tried making my manifest like so:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Main-Class: nu.educom.dbInsert.Main
    Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar
```

I moved around the connector in literally every directory existing in my program. It works fine when run from IDE.

The parameters given when running from terminal are used to connect to the local mysql server. All solutions I found on SO are regarding making it work in IDE. I found one very dated post on some other website, suggesting to set the classpath in manifest. I don't know what to exactly put there though or if it is even the thing I need.

the command to run the program in terminal :

`dbInsert -p:**** -u:root -d:products empty.csv`

where dbInsert is an alias:

`dbInsert="cd ~/desktop/projects/java/dbInsert/out/production/dbInsert/; java nu/educom/dbInsert/Main"`